# Prove that $X_2$ is a standard normal variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution

I'm facing difficulty in trying to prove the following:

> Let $X_1$, $X_2$ and $\xi$ be random variables such that $X_1 \sim \mathrm N(0,1)$ and $X_2 = |X_1| \!\cdot\! \xi$, where $\xi = \{-1, 1\}$ with $1/2$ probability. Also, $\xi$ is independent of $X_1$. Prove that $X_2 \sim \mathrm N(0, 1)$, where $\mathrm N(0, 1)$ is a standard normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

I managed to compute
$$P(X_2 \leq x) = \tfrac12 (1+P(|X_1| \leq x)).$$
But how to reduce the right hand side to $P(X_1 \leq x)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make an attempt to compute $P(X_2 \leq x)$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes, I did and got the following result:
(2 ≤ ) = 1/2 * (1 + (|1| ≤ )). How to reduce the RHS to (1 ≤ ) ?

Comment: For $\frac 1 2(1+P(|X_1| \leq x))=\frac 1 2+P(0<X_1 \leq x)=P(X_1 \leq 0)+P(0<X_1 \leq x)=P(X_1 \leq x)$.

Comment: So basically you're writing 1/2 * P( |X1| ≤ x) = P(-x ≤ X1 ≤ 0) * P(0 < X1 ≤ x) ?

Comment: No, $P(|X_1| \leq x)=2P(0<X_1 \leq x)$ by symmetry of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I got it. Thanks a lot, Sir. :)